# Stop cursor from changing on rollover hotspot

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

i've created an image including a hotspot area in dreamweaver. Whenever the mouse hovers over the hotspot the cursor changes to the hand-symbol. However, I do not want to change the cursor, as it is essential that the hotspot is "hidden".

Hope anyone can help me.

:)

Comment: Please try to add some style for your hotspot: display:none or visibility:hidden. And if you just want to change the cursor at this spot, try with this link for ref:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#element:hover { cursor: default; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the css cursor property to `default` like so:

```
cursor:default;
```

More information here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Tried, but somehow doen't seem to manage, sorry. Here is the code from the body: